# Employee Attrition - Binary Classification - Predicting leavers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary

I'm trying to wrap my head around what the standard or best approach is for identifying which employees in a business would be most at risk of leaving, given their features and an indicator column saying whether they've left the business.

My thoughts are to create a model that I train from both leaver and current employee data. (This is potentially where I'm setting up the problem wrong.)

The conflicting thing in this scenario, at least from my perception, is that you may find yourself feeding data into the model to train it, and then you will refeed the same data into the model to predict which employees will become leavers. Essentially, honing in on the false-positives, I suppose. i.e., the model predicts the employee will leave, but they are actually still at the business.

If anyone has advice they could shed, it'd be greatly appreciated.

All the best,
BS

Comment: Hi @TheCheeseWizard, Would you like to share more about features and data variables?

Comment: Hi @Kriti, thanks for your response. Features could be things like Age Bandings, Length of Service Bandings, Gender, & many more. 

So we could have lots of features available. Based on these features, can we predict if an employee would leave the business yes/no given that we know these features for employees who have left and also know these features for present employees.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ready answer, but I come up with some ideas that may help you approach this problem.

As I understood, the main difficulty in treating it as a binary classification of this data is that you are sure just about those who have left, but we don't know if those who stick to the company will leave it in a month.

So, maybe let's try transforming your problem from **will he/she leave?** to **will he/she leave after t time?**. If you have information about the time after someone left the company, it will allow you to not only operationalise your problem properly but also augment your training data. Let's take a look at the example of two employees:

- Robert - has been working here for two years and still does
- Karolina - left after one year of working

It's hard to classify leave/not leave as we don't know how to consider Robert here. However, if we take time into consideration we can transform it to input data like these ones:

- Robert, one year - stay
- Robert, two years - stay
- Karolina, three months - stay
- Karolina - eight months - stay
- Karolina - one year - left
- Karolina - fifteen months - left

Now it's simple to feed the model with this data and even it might have some prediction capabilities about when someone leaves the company and some interesting interpretations.

I'd like to underscore that I didn't check this solution, it's just an idea you can try and I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your insights. I just want to dive a little deeper with your example of two employees. I would hope, and correct me if I'm wrong, if we feed the model loads of the Roberts and Karolinas (other employees) - that we will be able to detect that there may be a relationship with Length of Service, in this example, and somebody leaving. If we then refed everybody back into the model, we could find that some people who are at the business also share the Length of Service with many others in the business that are likely to leave. Thus highlighting them to us.

Comment: My ambition is to provide intervention for people in the business who are most likely to leave. I would hope to predict who these employees are and which of their features are making the biggest contribution to the model predicting them to leave. I will put some thought into your proposed suggestion though, thanks for that. I would like to add though, if somebody has been at the business for a long time, their gender (or other features for that matter), for example, could suffer from class imbalance. For instance, we now have 6 lines of info in your example Male = 2 lines; female = 4 lines.

Comment: I think you perceive my thoughts correctly. About this imbalance - I see no obstacles to creating even 100 records for Karolina and 100 for Robert, I put it in this example to show that you can generate any record based on the raw data. But will it work? You must figure out by yourself on your data.